# Reinterpret cast to different type C++

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast

While reading about Reinterpret cast, I was checking the following code.

```
class Type1 {
public:

    Type1() {
        a = "Class Type 1";
    }
    void get1()
    {
        std::cout << a;
    }
private:
    std::string a;
};

class Type2 {
public:
    
    Type2() {
        b = "class Type 2";
    }

    void get2()
    {
        std::cout << b;
    }
private:
    std::string b;
};

int main()
{
    
    Type1* type1 = new Type1();

    //converting Pointer
    Type2* type2 = reinterpret_cast<Type2*>(type1);

    // accessing the function of class A 
    type2->get2(); 
}
```

After running the following code it prints in console `"Class Type 1"`

Now `type1` is pointer of type `Type1` and i cast it to `Type2` and store in `type2`.
Now when i call `type2->get2();`  Is it printing the data member `a` of instantiated `Type1` or compiler is dynamically changing function ?

Similarly in Following Code.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
  
class A { 
public: 
    void fun_a() 
    { 
        cout << " In class A\n"; 
    } 
}; 
  
class B { 
public: 
    void fun_b() 
    { 
        cout << " In class B\n"; 
    } 
}; 
  
int main() 
{ 
    // creating object of class B 
    B* x = new B(); 
  
    // converting the pointer to object 
    // referenced of class B to class A 
    A* new_a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(x); 
  
    // accessing the function of class A 
    new_a->fun_a(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

How "In class A" is getting printed? since I instantiated Class B ?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is one of C++'s many foot-shotguns. It rips through the type-system and will generally _compile_ code that is otherwise illegal, which leads to undefined behavior. It's good tool to know about, but very rarely is needed in practice. The few cases that it is needed still need caution to avoid writing invalid code.

Comment: Minor point: what's happening is early binding, what method gets called is decided at compile time based on the apparent type of the pointer, not its contents. The method will then try to make sense of the memory it is handed as its `this` pointer. But the compiler may very well decide to make demons fly out of your nose instead, especially with optimizations enabled. Never do this. See answer by @Human-Compiler

Comment: @Human-Compiler aren't most of the named casts except maybe `static_cast` footguns and/or code smells? `reinterpret_cast` - you're doing something horrible, `const_cast` - you're working around a broken API?, `dynamic_cast` - your design is weird

Comment: What you are seeing makes some sense because the two objects have the same size and shape.  Both just happen to have a `string` containing information set to different values by their respective constructors in the exact same "place". When the compiler generates incorrect code thanks to the cast, it still finds a `string`. Technically, you can't count on this behaviour, but practically, you should see this behaviour every time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are doing is **undefined behavior**. There is no correct answer to this.

It is illegal in C++ to use a pointer/reference resulting from a `reinterpret_cast` between two types of an unrelated hierarchy -- and so any code that generates from such cannot be reasoned about.

With undefined behavior, the compiler is free to do what it wishes with the invalid code. What you are experiencing may change between different compilers, optimization levels, and target architecture/system.

Answer (score -4):

You used conversion reinterpret_cast in your code

This conversion only tells the compiler to consider pointing to a different type, regardless of the type.
reinterpret_cast is the most illegal cast in C ++ that pays no attention to the destination and source data arrangement. And it just converts the value from one type to another.

Comment: "reinterpret_cast is the most illegal cast in C ++ that pays no attention to the destination and source data arrangement" if used right there is nothing illegal about a reinterpret cast. Problem is just that many believe reinterpret cast to be a any to any cast which it isnt at all.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` isn't an _"illegal cast"_ at all; there are plenty of valid uses of it such as converting pointers to numeric representations and back with a `std::uintptr_t`. It's just a cast that tells the compiler to take off the training wheels because I as the programmer know that the cast will produce a valid result (which is only true under specific cases)